# AutoComplete Combobox and Entity Framework

Tags: .net, winforms, entity-framework, autocomplete, combobox

I have a combobox with an autocomplete, that is loaded with some values via EF. What I would like is to have the autocomplete match on that field, and also a second field on the entity. To explain a bit more here's the data model:

```
AccountCode
ID   |   Ref   |   Desc
-----------------------
1    |   ABC   |  DEF
2    |   XZY   |  WUV
```

Currently the ref field is being loaded into a autocomplete, and so when the user types "AB" into the combo, ABC is presented to the user. What I would like is if the user types "DE" it would also come up with ABC.

Comment: are you sure the use wouldn't be surprised by this behavior ?

Comment: Perhaps, but its been specifically asked for by the client.

Comment: So you what do fuzzy search correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you can do this with a combo box. But you can do it with a text box and a button.

I have seen this functionality before in a banking application. There the requirement was that the user should be able to type the account number or the name of the account owner. They should also be able to select from a list.

Start with a text box, capture the change event and try to match against contents of Ref and Desc. Then place a button beside the text box which allows the user to select from a list.